# Providing Autofac with pre-resolved dependencies

Tags: c#, autofac

Please forgive me if I make any mistakes in asking this question as it is the first question I have asked on this site.

I am currently trying to add Autofac to an already existing project. I have been using Autofac for about 6 hours and C# for about 4 weeks, I am originally a Python developer so please forgive any C# ignorance. I currently have the following test method:`

```
    public static void BasicTest()
    {
        using (var scope= Program.container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            ITradeManager tm = scope.Resolve<ITradeManager>();
            List<IGameData> gamesList = new List<IGameData>();
            List<IUserData> usersList = new List<IUserData>();
            IScraperManager sc = scope.Resolve<IScraperManager>(new NamedParameter("sc",(scope.Resolve<UniScraper>(new NamedParameter("games", gamesList), new NamedParameter("users", usersList)))));
            IDatabaseIC db = scope.Resolve<IDatabaseIC>();
            IAppCore app = scope.Resolve<IAppCore>(
                new NamedParameter("tm", tm),
                new NamedParameter("sc", sc),
                new NamedParameter("db", db));

            IUserData tradeUser = scope.Resolve<IUserData>();

            app.Initialise(tradeUser, uniUser);

            app.Run();
        }
```

And have the following container setup:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<AppCore>().As<IAppCore>();
        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseInteractionControler>().As<IDatabaseIC>();
        builder.RegisterType<ScraperManager>().As<IScraperManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<TradeManager>().As<ITradeManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<GameData>().As<IGameData>();
        builder.RegisterType<UserData>().As<IUserData>();
        builder.RegisterType<Scrapers.Scrapers.Uni.UniScraper>().AsSelf().As<IBaseScraper>();
        builder.RegisterType<Scrapers.Scrapers.Hill.HillScraper>().AsSelf().As<IBaseScraper>();
        builder.RegisterType<Scrapers.Marathon.MarathonScraper>().AsSelf().As<IBaseScraper>();

        container = builder.Build();

        Tests.AppTest.BasicTest();

    }
```

My issue is that when I try to pass already resolved objects as parameters to Autofac for resolving IAppcore, it ignores the already resolved objects I'm passing as arguments, and instead of tries to resolve as if I did not pass any parameters to it at all!

Have I miss understood something or is there an obvious solution that I am too new to C# and Autofac to easily see?

If you are interested the project I originally wrote (and now converting to use Autofac) was a simple set of web scrapers that pulled in sports news from various different sites and collected them together in a handy little desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this test, one guess is that the names of your named parameters ("tm", "sc", "db") don't match the actual names of those parameters in the classes' constructors. If they don't match, Autofac doesn't throw an exception. It just resolves an instance of the registered type and ignores your `NamedParameter`.

To clarify, if your constructor looks like this:

```
public SomeConstructor(SomeRequiredDependency xyz)
```

Then the name specified in the `NamedParameter` must be "xyz".

```
public class RequiresDependency
{
    public RequiresDependency(Dependency dependency)
    {
        Dependency = dependency;
    }

    public Dependency Dependency { get; }
}

public class Dependency
{}

[TestClass]
public class AutofacTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ResolvesWithSpecifiedParameters()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<RequiresDependency>();
        builder.RegisterType<Dependency>();
        var myDependency = new Dependency();
        using (var container = builder.Build())
        {
            var resolved =
                container.Resolve<RequiresDependency>(new NamedParameter("dependency", myDependency));
            Assert.AreSame(myDependency, resolved.Dependency);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ResolvesWithRegisteredTypeIfParameterNameDoesntMatch()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<RequiresDependency>();
        builder.RegisterType<Dependency>();
        var myDependency = new Dependency();
        using (var container = builder.Build())
        {
            var resolved =
                container.Resolve<RequiresDependency>(new NamedParameter("x", myDependency));
            Assert.AreNotSame(myDependency, resolved.Dependency);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! so much I was clearly just being stupid....well at least I have got my first  SO question and also my first embarrassing SO question out the way in one go lol

Comment: There's no reason to be embarrassed. I'm sure the cognitive load of switching to a new language makes it hard to spot every detail.